# Problem rebuilding firmware

Tags: firmware

I'm new to reverse engineering.

I only want to add an app to my sat receiver.

To start I tried to extract my firmware with `./extract-firmware`, it's ok, and I have 1 ecos RTOS, and two cramfs in fmk/

BUT when I rebuild without any change, I have a message

```
Building new cramfs file system... (this may take several minutes!)
Directory data: 464 bytes
Everything: 1392 kilobytes
Super block: 76 bytes
CRC: b79c2a52
Remaining free bytes in firmware image: 856064
Processing 0 header(s) from /home/thehou/firmware-mod-kit/fmk/new-firmware.bin...
CRC update failed.

Firmware header not supported; firmware checksums may be incorrect.
New firmware image has been saved to: /home/thehou/firmware-mod-kit/fmk/new-firmware.bin`
```

So before I continue to add an app into my sat receiver, I want to know how can I rebuild my extracted firmware.

Perhaps must I extract with binwalk, but I don't know how to rebuild!

Thanks for your help.

Reference : this is the receiver [firmware](https://www.mediafire.com/file/sr9xcg99i8vhps2/ZINET-SATGN-CX300_Mini_Hybrid_Plus_V119_20032020.tar.gz/file)

Comment: Some firmwares have one or more text files containing hashes for files or filesystem images. Perhaps one of them no longer matches; maybe you used slightly different compression or something. See if a file like that exists, and update any hashes that may have changed.

Comment: Based on "firmware checksums may be incorrect.". There also could be a custom header with hashes instead.